# Onclick event not working as expected. Any idea why?

Tags: javascript, onclick, switch-statement

I am working on a *very* simple quiz javascript project, with a score and a start button, that generates questions when it gets clicked. I started work in the JS code by adding an onclick event listener, but it is not working as expected. Here is the code snippet that is supposed to be working but doesn't work, with a few comments. Keep in mind that I am very inexperienced in Javascript, so I may have misused some JS methods.

```
    function rng() {
 return Math.floor(Math.random * 10)
}
let stbt = document.getElementById("start")
stbt.addEventListener("click", function() { 
    stbt.remove //should remove the start button when it gets clicked.
    let q = document.createElement("p") //created an html paragraph.
    switch(rng()) {
        case 1:
         let qc = document.createTextNode("What is the capital of Chile?") 
         q.appendChild(qc) /*this should theoretically insert text into the html paragraph that gets created when the start button gets clicked,
         the switch statement that is switching the simple rng function should make it so that questions get generated randomly.*/
         break;
        case 2: 
         let qc = document.createTextNode("What is the highest mountain in Britain?")
         q.appendChild(qc)
         break;
        case 3: 
         let qc = document.createTextNode("What is the smallest country in the world?")
         q.appendChild(qc)
         break;
        case 4: 
         let qc = document.createTextNode("Alberta is a province of which country?")
         q.appendChild(qc)
         break;
        case 5: 
         let qc = document.createTextNode("How many countries still have the shilling as currency?")
         q.appendChild(qc)
         break;
        case 6: 
         let qc = document.createTextNode("Which is the only vowel not used as the first letter in a US State?")
         q.appendChild(qc)
         break;
        case 7: 
         let qc = document.createTextNode("What is the largest country in the world?")
         q.appendChild(qc)
         break;
        case 8: 
         let qc = document.createTextNode("Where would you find the River Thames?")
         q.appendChild(qc)
         break;
        case 9: 
         let qc = document.createTextNode("What is the hottest continent on Earth?")
         q.appendChild(qc)
         break;
        case 0: 
         let qc = document.createTextNode("What is the longest river in the world?")
         q.appendChild(qc)
         break;
    }
})
```

Comment: `stbt.remove()` <- needs parens. Also you never append `q` to anything, so that's why it doesn't show up.

Comment: You're also missing parens on `Math.random()` and you can't declare `qc` more than once, you'll need to declare it once outside of the `switch` and then assign it within the relevant `case`. And as Heretic Monkey mentioned you never append the `<p>` element to anything.

Comment: Could you simplify this? Maybe just one case?

Answer (score 1):

It is not the listener at fault here, but a number of small errors that are causing your code not to work.

- You are not [calling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#calling_functions) two functions: `Math.random` should be `Math.random()`, and `stbt.remove` should be `stbt.remove()`.
- Because of the way you have written your `switch` your `qc` variable is scoped across all your `case` statements, so you can't declare it again. You can fix this by either declaring it outside of the `switch` and assigning it in the `case` statements, or using braces to scope the variable to each `case`.

```
let qc; //<--- declare qc;
  switch (rng()) {
    case 1:
      qc = document.createTextNode("What is the capital of Chile?")
      ...
      break;
    case 2:
      qc = document.createTextNode("What is the highest mountain in Britain?")
      ...
```

or

```
  switch (rng()) { 
    case 1: { //<--- braces to scope variable declaration
      let qc = document.createTextNode("What is the capital of Chile?")
      ...
      break;
    }
    case 2: {
      let qc = document.createTextNode("What is the highest mountain in Britain?")
      ...
      break;
    }
    case 3: {
      ...
```

- Lastly, you never append your `<p>` element to the DOM. You'll need to either query an element to append to, or as in the example below, append directly to the `document.body`

The `switch` statement tends to be quite verbose and so it helps to avoid duplication as much as possible. Instead of appending the new text node within each `case` you can instead move it after the `switch` and call it just once.

```
stbt.addEventListener("click", function () {
  ...
  let qc;
  switch (rng()) {
    case 1: 
      ...
  }
  // Avoid duplication by appending once at the end
  q.appendChild(qc)
  document.body.appendChild(q) //<--- append <p> to DOM
});
```

```js
function rng() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10); //<--- parentheses needed to call function;
}

const stbt = document.getElementById("start");

stbt.addEventListener("click", function () {
  stbt.remove(); //<--- parentheses needed to call function;
  let q = document.createElement("p");
  let qc; //<--- declare qc;
  switch (rng()) {
    case 1: {
      let qc = document.createTextNode("What is the capital of Chile?")
      break;
      }
    case 2:
      qc = document.createTextNode("What is the highest mountain in Britain?")
      break;
    case 3:
      qc = document.createTextNode("What is the smallest country in the world?")
      break;
    case 4:
      qc = document.createTextNode("Alberta is a province of which country?")
      break;
    case 5:
      qc = document.createTextNode("How many countries still have the shilling as currency?")
      q.appendChild(qc)
      break;
    case 6:
      qc = document.createTextNode("Which is the only vowel not used as the first letter in a US State?")
      break;
    case 7:
      qc = document.createTextNode("What is the largest country in the world?")
      break;
    case 8:
      qc = document.createTextNode("Where would you find the River Thames?")
      q.appendChild(qc)
      break;
    case 9:
      qc = document.createTextNode("What is the hottest continent on Earth?")
      break;
    case 0:
      qc = document.createTextNode("What is the longest river in the world?")
      break;
  }
  // Avoid duplication by appending once at the end
  q.appendChild(qc)
  document.body.appendChild(q) //<--- append <p> to the DOM
});
```

```html
<button type="button" id='start'>Start</button>
```

---

**Making it more general**

Using a `switch` can be very clear in showing what is happening, but it does lead to a lot of duplication. If you wanted to add a question you would need to add a whole new `case` statement as well as change the constant within your `rng()` function. To avoid this you might want to think about other structures that might serve your purpose.

Here is an example using an Array to store the questions which is accessed by index using the returned value from the `rng()` (which has been changed to accept a `max` value). With this structure, adding a question is simply a matter of adding to the array, the rest takes care of itself.

```js
function rng(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max)
}

const questions = [
  "What is the capital of Chile?",
  "What is the highest mountain in Britain?",
  "What is the smallest country in the world?",
  "Alberta is a province of which country?",
  "How many countries still have the shilling as currency?",
  "Which is the only vowel not used as the first letter in a US State?",
  "What is the largest country in the world?",
  "Where would you find the River Thames?",
  "What is the hottest continent on Earth?",
  "What is the longest river in the world?",
]

const stbt = document.getElementById("start")
const div = document.getElementById("questions")

stbt.addEventListener("click", function () {
  // pass the length of the questions array as the max value for the rng()
  const questionIndex = rng(questions.length);
  const question = questions[questionIndex];

  stbt.remove();

  const q = document.createElement("p");
  const qc = document.createTextNode(question)

  q.appendChild(qc)
  div.appendChild(q)
});
```

```html
<button type="button" id='start'>Start</button>
<div id='questions'></div>
```

Comment: Tysm for the help. The weird thing is that the stackoverflow code snippet runs fine, but my vsc project doesn't eliminate the button and display the question on the onclick event. I rechecked ids and possible syntax errors but I can't seem to find anything wrong, it may be something in my html/css code, although i didnt write a lot there so i strongly doubt it :/

Comment: Where are you running it?

Comment: I am running and debugging it from VSC

Comment: Without knowing more about your code and how you're serving it from VSC it's hard to say. You might want to post another question. If this answer helped you, please accept it.